Why does CH3ONa with CH3OH leads to E2 reaction with 2°alkyl halide? Why not Sn2?
2° alkyl halide with strong base/ nucleophile can undergo Sn2 or E2 reaction depending on the other factors involved like temperature, solvent etc. So how does the presence of CH3OH ( which is a poor nucleophile and weak base ) can lead to elimination and not substitution?

Methanol is not a strong nucleophile. But methanethiol $(\ce{CH3-SH})$ is.

First of all,
$\ce{CH3OH}$ is a weak base and a poor nucleophile compared to stronger nucleophiles like alkoxides or halide ions. However, methanol acts as a polar protic solvent, which stabilizes the carbocation intermediate and favors E1 or SN1 mechanisms.
So,

If elimination occurs, it is likely via an E1 mechanism, not E2. Methanol doesn’t have the basicity required for E2.
If substitution occurred, it would be via SN1, where methanol attacks the carbocation to form the substitution product.

Preference for Elimination Over Substitution:

Heat: If the reaction conditions involve heating, elimination becomes more favorable because elimination has a higher entropy gain compared to substitution.
Steric Factors: If the $2^{\circ}$ alkyl halide has significant steric hindrance near the carbon center, substitution is less favorable, making elimination more competitive.
Carbocation Stability: The stability of the carbocation intermediate influences the reaction pathway. For a stable carbocation, elimination may dominate, especially with sufficient $\beta$-hydrogens.

Hence, Methanol alone isn’t strongly biased toward elimination, but in the presence of Higher temperatures and Sterically hindered alkyl halide, The nucleophilic attack in SN1 is less likely, tipping the balance toward E1.
Hope this helps.

1-chloro, 2-enthylcyclopentane is reacting with NaOCH3, CH3OH, the question is about the mechanism of the reaction and the answer given is E2 but strong bases ( unlike CH3OH) promote E2 reactions. So is the answer wrong?

@Electrophile if $\ce{NaOCH3}$ is present, then it will act as strong base and hence E2 mechanism would be followed. I think in that reaction, $\ce{CH3OH}$ would only react as solvent instead of primary base. So, the answer is correct.

Since a polar aprotic solvent favors SN2 reactions, any of the above anions or salt can be used together with DMSO, DMF, etc., such as OH–/DMSO or CH3ONa/DMF. However, sometimes you may see a combination like CH3ONa/CH3OH, which is the combination of CH3O– together with its conjugate acid CH3OH. It may seem contradictory, so why is a strong nucleophile for SN2 combined with a solvent for SN1? The reality is that CH3ONa here still acts as a strong nucleophile and can be used for an SN2 reaction, and CH3OH is the solvent for CH3ONa . This is from a website (can't put link). So is the ans E2/Sn2?
